# Make org-drill allow reviewing "empty" cards

Tags: org-mode, org-drill

I'm trying to use `org-drill` with cards made up of one-line headings, which the documentation considers an "**empty card**" (that is, one without a body).

The recommended way to make them show up in drill sessions is to add an empty comment to the body, like a line with only `#`. It works, but I'm trying to fix this in a way cleaner than mass-editing my org file.

---

I found the variable `org-drill-card-type-alist`, whose default value is

```
      '((nil org-drill-present-simple-card)
        ("simple" org-drill-present-simple-card)
        ("twosided" org-drill-present-two-sided-card nil t)
        (...))
```

The `t` at the end of the `twosided` sexp means `drill-empty-p`, which means:

> When supplied, DRILL-EMPTY-P is a boolean value, default nil.
>   When non-nil, cards of this type will be presented during tests
>   **even if their bodies are empty**.

This seems to be exactly what I want, so I set the `nil` (default) and `simple` (for good measure) card types like this, using `customize-set-variable`:

```
      '((nil org-drill-present-simple-card nil t)
        ("simple" org-drill-present-simple-card nil t)
        ("twosided" org-drill-present-two-sided-card nil t)
        (...))
```

I eval the sexp / restart org-mode / restart Emacs, and still `M-x org-drill` ignores the empty cards.

Am I doing something wrong? Is this a bug? Are there any workarounds?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `DRILL-EMPTY-P` parameter in entries of `org-drill-card-type-alist` is only
considered for cards with an explicit `DRILL_CARD_TYPE` in function `org-drill-entry-status`.

As a workaround treat drill-cards with nil card type as non-empty if the `DRILL-EMPTY-P` parameter of that type is set:

```el
(defun org-drill-entry-status-workaround (oldfun &rest args)
  "Call adviced `org-drill-entry-status' as OLDFUN with ARGS.
Temporarily let `org-entry-empty-p' return nil for empty drill cards
with DRILL_CARD_TYPE nil."
  (let ((oldfun-entry-empty-p (symbol-function 'org-entry-empty-p)))
    (cl-letf (((symbol-function 'org-entry-empty-p)
               (lambda ()
                 (and (funcall oldfun-entry-empty-p) ;; in principle the old fun
                      ;; with the exception:
                      (null (and
                             (org-drill-entry-p)
                             (null (org-entry-get (point) "DRILL_CARD_TYPE"))
                             (nth 3 (assoc nil org-drill-card-type-alist)))))))) ;; DRILL-EMPTY-P
      (apply oldfun args))))

(advice-add 'org-drill-entry-status :around #'org-drill-entry-status-workaround)
```

With this workaround `org-drill` works as you expect it in the following test org buffer with `emacs-version` 25.3.1 and `org-drill` 2.6.1.

```org
* first                                                               :drill:
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       97a78aeb-8e62-4243-b49b-faccb12dd31c
  :END:
* second                                                              :drill:
  :PROPERTIES:
  :ID:       c0acc9c5-bdca-4414-96bb-61ea2aeb85e1
  :END:

* Local Variables                                                     :noexport:
# Local Variables:
# org-drill-card-type-alist: ((nil org-drill-present-simple-card nil t))
# end:
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just installed `org-drill` and this behavior seems a bit unsafe to me. It's documented, but I still spent quite a bit of time figuring out why the verb card from the `spanish.org` example never shows up. Turns out it's empty.

I'm paranoid that I would occasionally make such mistakes and lose cards forever if it ignores empty ones. So I just redefined the `org-drill-entry-empty-p` function to always say it's non-empty.

```
(use-package org-drill
  ...
  :config
  (defun org-drill-entry-empty-p () nil)
  )
```